# jQuery JSON Callback says 'Undefined'

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm creating this script which loads the data from JSON which is encoded in a PHP file (the JSON is valid).

When a div is clicked on, it should show the data from the jQuery, which is done here:

```
function quickView(pid) {
    $.getJSON('project.php', { id: pid, view: 'true' }, function(data) {
      $('#view-' + pid).html('<p>' + data.name + '</p>'
        + '<p>' + data.deadline + '</p>');
    });
}
```

The HTML:

```
<a href="project.php?id=1">
    <div class="row-null">
        <p>An example project</p>
    </div>
</a>
<div class="row-null quick-view" id="view-1" title="Quick View" onclick="quickView(1);">
    <p><img src="img/pixel.png" height="5" width="9" alt="" /></p>
</div>
```

However when I click on it, it opens and says Undefined...

The JSON when outputted:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Another example project",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
        "deadline": "Tuesday 24th August 2010"
    }
]
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is returning an array, so you want data[0].name.